# Rolling rows in SQL table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to create an SQL table that has no more than n rows of data. When a new row is inserted, I'd like the oldest row removed to make space for the new one.

Is there a typical way of handling this within SQLite?

Should manage it with some outside (third-party) code?

Answer (score 17):

Expanding on [Alex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977341/rolling-rows-in-sql-table/1977357#1977357), and assuming you have an incrementing, non-repeating serial column on table `t` named `serial` which can be used to determine the relative age of rows:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER ten_rows_only AFTER INSERT ON t
   BEGIN
     DELETE FROM t WHERE serial <= (SELECT serial FROM t ORDER BY serial DESC LIMIT 10, 1);
   END;
```

This will do nothing when you have fewer than ten rows, and will `DELETE` the lowest serial when an `INSERT` would push you to eleven rows.

**UPDATE**

Here's a slightly more complicated case, where your table records "age" of row in a column which *may contain duplicates*, as for example a `TIMESTAMP` column tracking the insert times.

```
sqlite> .schema t
CREATE TABLE t (id VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ts TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
CREATE TRIGGER ten_rows_only AFTER INSERT ON t
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM t WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 10, -1);
  END;
```

Here we take for granted that we cannot use `id` to determine relative age, so we delete everything after the first 10 rows ordered by timestamp.  (SQLite imposes an arbitrary order on rows sharing the same `ts`).

Comment: wouldn't this always delete the first row?

Comment: @aronchick, no - the scalar subquery will evaluate to NULL if there is no record in the 11th position (AFTER our INSERT of possibly the 11th row), and so the `WHERE` clause then becomes `WHERE serial <= NULL`, which won't match anything.

Comment: What if the _id is auto-incremented.  Couldn't this code be accomplished with the _id instead of TIMESTAMP or serial?  Especially when a TIMESTAMP is not always part of the table schema...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, that's equivalent to what I called a "serial" column, above, yes.

Comment: What does the -1 stand for?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, [`LIMIT 10, -1` is the same as `LIMIT -1 OFFSET 10`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

Comment: What about the size of the table on the disk? Would it stay fixed or it will continue to grow as long as records are being added.

Comment: You will probably run into a deadlock using this approach. We tried something similar in our SQL Server DB and when we tested our system with JMeter we found deadlocks.

Comment: Why was it needed to sort DESC ? old timestamps are supposed to be removed. Or is it because of the " LIMIT 10, -1" ? If so, I think it leaves us with 11 items instead of 10. Is it possible? Or am I doing something wrong? As for the trigger, isn't it better to make the condition to be when the size is more than the required max limit?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, perhaps you should ask a separate question?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, yes it's because of the "-1".  No, it leaves you with 10 items.  Yes, I suspect you're doing something wrong, and we can get to the bottom of it if we [see your exact circumstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). No, I don't think a trigger that's aware of the source table size (which these are not) is better.

Comment: @pilcrow OK thank you. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62242272/878126

Answer (score 4):

Seems SQLite's support for triggers can suffice: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 1):

article on fixed queues in sql: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/01/11/how-to-implement-a-queue-in-sql

should be able to use the same technique to implement "rolling rows"

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210728070004/https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/01/11/how-to-implement-a-queue-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

This would be something like how you would do it. This assumes that `my_id_column` is auto-incrementing and is the ordering column for the table.

```
-- handle rolls forward
-- deletes the oldest row
create trigger rollfwd after insert on my_table when (select count() from my_table) > max_table_size
   begin
   delete from my_table where my_id_column = (select min(my_id_column) from my_table);
   end;

-- handle rolls back
-- inserts an empty row at the position before oldest entry
-- assumes all columns option or defaulted
create trigger rollbk after delete on my_table when (select count() from my_table) < max_table_size
   begin
   insert into my_table (my_id_column) values ((select min(my_id_column) from my_table) - 1);
   end;
```