# Delete all but latest 500 rows from sqlite database

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, delete-row

My SQL isn't bad but SQLite on iOS constantly catches me out.

I have a table where I want to limit the number of rows to around 500, so when it hits a trigger point of say 550 it will delete the earliest 50 rows.

It's rolling so with time the id wont always start  at one and the user can delete rows so the id is non-sequential.

I have a `juliandate` field (`double`) but I'm not sure that's any use

```
DELETE FROM contents WHERE id > '0' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 50
DELETE FROM contents ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Documentation says that's OK but it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: How does it fail? Error message, or just doesn't delete anything or deletes the wrong things? Why don't you use the date field so you can delete the oldest 50?

Comment: @NickBull, `1.` Sqlite3 is not that verbose about errors: `Error: near "LIMIT": syntax error`. `2.` there might not be a date field.

Comment: @MishaAkovantsev 1. That error message is plenty enough to see that there is a syntax error rather than the error being that the wrong records are deleted. 2. The OP says "I have a juliandate field"

Comment: @NickBull `1.` true, but was not helpful for me. `2.` true, overlooked it completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something along these lines, maybe?

```
delete from contents where juliandate <= (
    select max(juliandate) from (
        select juliandate from contents order by juliandate limit 0, 50));
```

You can use id instead of juliandate or any other field which value increases with every insert.

Comment: StackOverflow - making the internet more awesome than porn and kittens alone can - thank you user1096188!

Comment: This didn't work for me, while thecr0w's answer did. Check that one out if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 9):

Keep latest 500 records:

```
delete
from table_name
where _id not
  in (select _id
    from table_name
    order by
      _id desc
    limit 500)
```

Comment: congratulations, but it just depends.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM contents WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50)
```

`DESC` means `5,4,3,2,1`, use it to delete `the freshest` records.
`ASC` means `1,2,3,4,5`, use it to delete `the earliest` records.

Here is an example:

```
$ sqlite3 /tmp/del_rows.sqlite3
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);
INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('b');
INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('c');
INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('d');
INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('e');
INSERT INTO t (value) VALUES ('f');
SELECT * FROM t;
-- 1|a
-- 2|b
-- 3|c
-- 4|d
-- 5|e
-- 6|f

-- Deleting 2 top rows:
DELETE FROM t WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2);
SELECT * FROM t;
-- 3|c
-- 4|d
-- 5|e
-- 6|f

-- And again:
DELETE FROM t WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM t ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2);
SELECT * FROM t;
-- 5|e
-- 6|f
```

Comment: This will delete n rows each time, but not "Delete all but latest 500 rows".That means keep latest 500 records, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. This should be what you are looking for:

```
DELETE FROM contents WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT id FROM contents ORDER BY id LIMIT 50 ASC);
```

Read also, similar question: [Keep only N last records in SQLite database, sorted by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528117/keep-only-n-last-records-in-sqlite-database-sorted-by-date)

Comment: Alas no, not sure why not but SQLite seems extra fanickity.

Comment: Do you mean keep latest 500 records?