# Sqlite query to keep the last 5 searches on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my android app.

Each time I open the search activity of my app, I want to display a list of my search history but limited to the latest 5 searched items.

```
DBHelper searchDBHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); //extends SQLiteOpenHelper
//lookup the historical data from the DB first and pass it to the adapter
try {
    searchDBHelper.deletePlaceSearchItems();
    hSearchDao = searchDBHelper.getHSearchDao();
    searchArrayList = new LinkedList<>(hSearchDao.queryForAll());
    historicalSearchAdapter = new HistoricalSearchAdapter(searchArrayList);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

my `SearchDBHelper.java` has the following delete method in it which is called above:

```
public void deletePlaceSearchItems() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String[] args ={"5"};
        db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM placesearch " +
                "WHERE id < (" +
                " SELECT MIN(id)" +
                " FROM (SELECT id" +
                " FROM placesearch" +
                " ORDER BY date DESC" +
                " LIMIT ?))", args);
}
```

The sqlite query code was obtained from here: [Keep only N last records in SQLite database, sorted by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528117/keep-only-n-last-records-in-sqlite-database-sorted-by-date)

I keep on running the app but the code does not seem to delete anything at all. Also not sure how I can debug this as no error message was printed to my logs. This is what my sqlite db looks like inside - it has 6 items:

[image: sqlite database]

This is my ormlite_config.txt file:

```
#################################
# --table-start--
dataClass=Model.PlaceSearch
tableName=placesearch
# --table-fields-start--
# --field-start--
fieldName=id
columnName=id
generatedId=true
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=placeSearch
columnName=places_search
# --field-end--
# --field-start--
fieldName=time
columnName=time
# --field-end--
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
#################################
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your database, I'm not seeing any column with the name `date`; you have a field named `time`.

You need to change your code like:

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM placesearch " +
                "WHERE id < (" +
                " SELECT MIN(id)" +
                " FROM (SELECT id" +
                " FROM placesearch" +
                " ORDER BY time DESC" +
                " LIMIT ?))", args);
```

Comment: OK agreed and made the adjustment - well spotted, but its still not working. I have posted my ormlite_config code as well.

Comment: @Simon: The query is working fine for me!!! Are you checking the same database file were these changes happening ?

Comment: OK . Your code is actually correct but the method call should change to db.execSQL(). rawQuery does not delete anything unless you call moveToFirst() according to this thread which is highly confusing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337764/android-delete-query

Comment: @Simon: Thanks for the comment. It is a valuable information. Thank you :) Happy coding !!!