# sqlite, trigger when a table reaches MAX count of records

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

Is it possible to add a trigger in sqlite3 in order to remove N (older, or at least lines that meet a filter) lines when the table reaches a maximum number of records? If yes, how?

Simple example: A log database contains at most 1000 entries. When the 1000th entry is inserted 
the first 100 are removed. That way we can wrap around after a certain size is reached.

Rings a bell?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [Rolling rows in SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1977341/132382)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that worked for me using a helper table named `bookkeepings`

```
create table bookkeepings (bk_name text primary key, bk_value integer not null);

insert or replace into bookkeepings values ('Max Entries', 50);
insert or replace into bookkeepings values ('Qty Entries', 0);

create trigger log_entries_limit_trigger before insert on log_entries
  for each row
  when (select bk_value from bookkeepings where bk_name = 'Qty Entries')
    >= (select bk_value from bookkeepings where bk_name = 'Max Entries')
  begin
    delete from log_entries
      where timestamp = (select timestamp from log_entries order by timestamp limit 1);
  end;

create trigger log_entries_count_insert_trigger after insert on log_entries
  for each row
  begin
    update bookkeepings set bk_value = bk_value + 1 where bk_name = 'Qty Entries';
  end;

create trigger log_entries_count_delete_trigger after delete on log_entries
  for each row
  begin
    update bookkeepings set bk_value = bk_value - 1 where bk_name = 'Qty Entries';
  end;
```

You could change the `limit 1` to `limit 100` to delete 100 rows.

Comment: Cannot 'Qty Entries' be computed as needed?  (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log_entries` ?)

Comment: @pilcrow, sure, you can use COUNT(*), but that is an O(N) operation, and I'd prefer not to incur that cost on every insertion.