# Delete entry in SQLite database automatically (android)

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

How can I tell my database to automatically delete the entry with the lowest ID when a new row is created? 
I want this to be done when there are more than ten rows in the table.

Here is my createEntry method:

```
public long createEntry(String latitude, String longitude) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);     
    cv.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);



    return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the "oldest" row with the smallest id use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977477/1267661) from [Rolling rows in SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1977341/1267661).

However a SQLite table has a maximum number of row ids. Once this limit has been reached, a table that uses `integer primary key autoincrement` will search for old, unused row ids for new insertions. This could result in the latest row having the *lowest* row id (and being deleted first).

Understand that this limit is typically 9223372036854775807. If you expect to exceed this many insertions in your smartphone app:

1. You're nuts.
2. You can use timestamps in your trigger instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Well I might not use that many entries, but I would like to limit the amount of entries to make the database easier to handle. I have a bunch of different databases, each database updates frequently and I only need like the last ten rows of information, thus making the other ones uninteresting.

Comment: "I would like to limit the amount of entries to make the database easier to handle" The link I posted uses a trigger which prevents you from having to access the database multiple times to check the row count and delete the unnecessary rows, the trigger does this in one access.