# Sorting SQLite table with "ORDER BY" - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a SQLite db for my highscores table.  Currently I am having trouble checking if the new score makes the highscores and also sorting the highscores table.

When the game is over, Results.java is called.

**Results.java**

```
total_score = dh.calculateTotalScore(score, percentage);
low_score = dh.check(score, percentage, total_score);
if(total_score > low_score) {
    dh.delete(10);
    dh.insert(score, percentage, total_score);
} else {
    dh.insert(score, percentage, 9999999);
}
dh.sort();
```

All the methods being called in `Results.java` are coming from `DatabaseHelper.java`.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public void sort() {
    db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + TOTAL_SCORE, null);
}

public long calculateTotalScore(long score, int percentage) {
    long i;
    return i = (percentage * 1000) + score;
}

public long check(long score, int percentage, long sum) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + TOTAL_SCORE + " FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
    long count = c.getCount();
    long low_score;
    if(count == 10) {
        c.moveToLast();
        low_score = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TOTAL_SCORE));
        return low_score;
    } else {
        return count;
    }
}

public long insert(long score, int percentage, long total_score) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SCORE, score);
    values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);
    values.put(TOTAL_SCORE, total_score);

    return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, values);
}

public void delete(int row) { 
    db.delete(DB_TABLE, RANK + "=" + row, null);
}
```

The output for TOTAL_SCORE is being displayed as follows:

- 1
- 2
- 40851
- 1
- 2
- 40804
- 60811
- 60811
- 50816

What I desire is for the output to be in numerical order.  Like this:

- 1
- 1
- 2
- 2
- 40804
- 40851
- 50816
- 60811
- 60811

The order they are in above is (I think) just the order they were inserted into the db.  No errors happen when the program runs and the program does not crash.  More code can be provided if needed.

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem? Can you be specific about it. What I means is you want to sort your high score or you want sql returning high score.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  What I want is for the output to be sorted in numericle order.  In otherwords the order needs to be 1,1,2,2,40804,40851,50816,60811,60811.  I will update my opening post for more clarity.

Comment: I suggest using a Trigger to have SQLite automatically maintain the ten highest scores or keep all of the scores and use the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Just use `order by` clause in your `sql` . If you are concerned how many rows you want you can also use `limit` clause with your `sql.` and also if you are concerned about duplicate result then you can use `group by`

Comment: @Sam Your answer is what I need.  I want to constantly maintain ONLY the top 10 scores and I want them to be sorted from the highest to lowest.  From my quick research Triggers look fairly complex.  Would you have an example/link on how Triggers can automatically maintain a highscores?

Comment: Triggers do seem daunting at first, but you'll get it. This question addresses something _very_ similar: [Rolling rows in SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1977341/1267661). (The second answer points to the documentation, which might help too.)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your entire class.  For example, I can't tell if TOTAL_SCORE resolves to just a column name, or if it might be something like "SUM(SCORE_VALUE)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT` does not modify anything; your `sort` function has no effect.
(The `rawQuery` function *returns* the sorted list of records, but you ignore it.)

You have to put the `ORDER BY` clause into the query that is used to display the scores.

Comment: Well I was going about this all wrong a guess.  I don't just want to display them in a sorted order, I want to maintain them while they are in storage in a sorted order.  I guess my new question is if there is a SQL query that can be run on a db that will return nothing, but sort a table according to a specific column and save the table after the sort.  From there I can fetch from it as I want and display.

Comment: Tables in SQL do not have a defined order, and records often get reordered by `SELECT`s. If you want to have a specific order, you *must* use `ORDER BY` in every `SELECT`.