# How to set a max items for a specific table using Trigger, in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is a simple question.

### Background

I'm supposed to have max of 400 rows in some table, based on timestamp field, so old ones will be removed automatically. For here, let's say it's 3 instead.

The table has various fields, but the timestamp is what's important here.

### The problem

Even though I've succeeded (looked [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1977477/878126)), for some reason it got me to a max of an additional item, so I just adjusted it accordingly. This means that instead of 3, I got 4 items.

```
private const val MAX_ITEMS = 3
private val TIMESTAMP_FIELD = "timestamp"


private val DELETE_FROM_CALL_LOG_TILL_TRIGGER =
        String.format(
                "CREATE TRIGGER %1\$s INSERT ON %2\$s 
                 WHEN (select count(*) from %2\$s)>%3\$s 
                 BEGIN 
                 DELETE FROM %2\$s WHERE %2\$s._id IN " +
                        "(SELECT %2\$s._id FROM %2\$s ORDER BY %2\$s.$TIMESTAMP_FIELD DESC LIMIT %3\$d, -1);
                 END;"
                , "delete_till_reached_max", TABLE_NAME, MAX_ITEMS - 1)
```

### What I've tried

I tried :

- Change the condition to just being insertion (meaning without the `WHEN` part)
- Change  `LIMIT %3\$d, -1` to `LIMIT -1 OFFSET %3\$d` . Also tried a different number than "-1" (tried 0, because I thought it's extra).

### The questions

1. How come I had to use `MAX_ITEMS - 1` instead of just `MAX_ITEMS` ? Why does it leave me with 4items instead of 3   ?
2. Does it matter if I have `WHEN` there? Is it better?

Comment: If it's not absolutely critical that there be 400 items, you could perhaps delete from the table where rowid < max(rowid) - 400. Rowid will usually (if you don't fiddle with it) be an auto incrementing number

Comment: @CaiusJard Why should I use ID? It's always increasing...

Comment: Er, yes.. I thought that was what you were asking - a better/easier way to maintain 400 items is to use an incrementing number and delete everything LTE the current number minus 400. This means the delete can be done with math on something you know easily (the id of the just inserted record) rather than having to sort N items by date desc, take the date of the 400th item and delete everything LTE it

Comment: If the ID is always increasing and SQLite only supports `FOR EACH ROW` triggers, then we are talking about deleting one single row. This is `delete from mytable where id = (select min(id) from mytable group by null having count(*) = 400)` in a before-insert trigger or `> 400` in an after-row trigger.

Comment: Guys, the field I'm supposed to work on is not the ID. It's the timestamp (of Long type). I need to remove the oldest ones from this field, meaning the ones with lowest values. If I use ID, it might make sense only if I always add new items that have newer IDs, and are sorted as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have omitted the `BEFORE | AFTER` clause, so it's `BEFORE` by default. This means you are counting the rows *before*  the insert, not after it.
2. This depends. At first, when the table has not reached the limit yet, the quick count lookup may save you some time, as you avoid the more complicated delete. But as soon as the table is full, you'll have to delete anyway, so counting is just additional work to do.

This should work:

```
private const val MAX_ITEMS = 3
private val TIMESTAMP_FIELD = "timestamp"

private val DELETE_FROM_CALL_LOG_TILL_TRIGGER =
  String.format(
    "CREATE TRIGGER %1\$s AFTER INSERT ON %2\$s 
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN 
       DELETE FROM %2\$s WHERE _id =
         (SELECT _id FROM %2\$s ORDER BY %4\$s DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET %3\$s);
     END;"
    , "delete_till_reached_max", TABLE_NAME, MAX_ITEMS, TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
```

Once there are 400 rows in the table, you can just as well call the trigger something like `trg_keep_rowcount_constant` and remove `GROUP BY null HAVING COUNT(*) > %3\$s` from the code.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ea3867e20e85927a2de047908771f4f1

Comment: Can you please show the correct one, then? As for the counting, since the max will be reached eventually, do you recommend to remove the count? Isn't it a relatively quick check? Is it not O(1) ?

Comment: The trigger looks correct. With `limit 400, 1` you delete the oldest row. (You could change `IN` to `=` because it's never more than one row you want to delete.) I'd remove the `WHEN` clause, for once you hit the 400 rows, it will always be 400 rows and the `WHEN` clause just adds unnecessary work. In order to count rows, the whole table must be read. This is not much with only 400 rows, but it's work that can be avoided.

Comment: Really? I thought that it has a cached result of how many are there, and that it could be cached for the query of the rest of the clause. Anyway, can you please write the code after the changes you've suggested? It's hard to get the pieces as you write them...

Comment: There is nothing to cache. The trigger fires after each row, so the row count must be retrieved each and every time. As to your trigger: It works, right? So you could just keep it as is or remove the `WHEN` clause. I've added the trigger with slight changes to my answer. I made `AFTER INSERT` and `FOR EACH ROW` explicit. I also changed the `IN` clause, actually not knowing whether this performs better or worse. You can use my version or keep yours or mix the two. Whatever you prefer :-)

Comment: Wait why did you add "FOR EACH ROW" ? Wasn't the "after" enough? The "SELECT " is also very different, not ordering by timestamp at all. The ID shouldn't be the one to decide which to delete and which won't .

Comment: SQLite only supports `FOR EACH ROW` triggers. I put this clause into the trigger to make this explicit. It doesn't change anything, it just makes it more obvious to the reader what the trigger actually does. As to the timestamp: why involve it? You said the ID is also incrementing, so I just stick to the ID, which we need anyway. The simpler the query, the faster it (hopefully) is :-)

Comment: No, you can't assume anything about the relation between ID and timestamp. Timestamp don't always increment compared to ID (example is when you restore data, or when you have batch insertion of multiple items that are not sorted by timestamp). Simple doesn't mean correct. And I never wrote that ID is what I'm looking for. I wrote timestamp only. Even the code includes timestamp.

Comment: I am sorry. A column just called `timestamp` is usually acsending in a table and when you mentioned that the ID is incrementing, I thought that it didn't matter then whether to use one or the other. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated my code accordingly.

Comment: But I wrote that I need it about timestamp... About `FOR EACH ROW` , you mean it doesn't do anything? It can be removed? And what is the remark in the answer about "Once there are 400 rows in the table..." ? I've tested the new trigger. Seem to work well now. You get +1 for now. Will get V for explaining about it.

Comment: Yes, `FOR EACH ROW` can be removed. In contrast, in standard SQL there are two types of triggers, those that fire for each row and those that fire once per statement. In standard SQL you use `FOR EACH ROW` to create a row trigger and omit it to create a statement trigger. SQLite only features row triggers, so it interprets both, triggers with `FOR EACH ROW` and without, row triggers. So in SQLite you can omit `FOR EACH ROW` and it still is a row trigger, because SQLIte violates the SQL standard here. For readers not knowing this , it may be confusing. I'd keep `FOR EACH ROW` for this reason.

Comment: As to "Once there are 400 rows in the table": I had a query before that took the pain to count rows in order to decide whether to delete or not. Once there are 400 rows in the table, however, there will always be 400 rows in it, because everytime you insert a row you delete another. You could then decide to remove the counting, because it will always be 401 after insterting a row. In the new query I don't count anymore, so this remark no longer applies. (If the timestamp were unique, we could delete the row with the minimum timestamp and would then probably have a counting query again.)

Comment: I think something is actually wrong on the trigger. It worked at first, but the moment I added more items, it stopped changing what I get, entirely. I also tried to remove the "FOR EACH ROW". Still doesn't work. Something is very weird here. Going back to the solution I made, it worked fine. I can't use this solution, but I also don't know what is wrong on it. Can you please read it well to see if you've made a mistake?

Comment: Correct, I mistakenly removed the `DESC` from the `ORDER BY` clause. I've added it  now and the trigger should be working fine now. I've also added a demo fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why don't you order it as I did... I thought it's something with the OFFSET. BTW, the "FOR EACH ROW" can indeed safely be removed. The assumption that it is always on the max is incorrect though. I didn't give you any clue to assume it, and even though in reality it's rare in my case, I do allow to delete rows from the table, so it's incorrect. Then again, I prefer to avoid the extra query because I don't think that it's worth it anyway. Thank you. Have V. You've earned it :)

Comment: Say, do you recommend avoiding using triggers? It seems like something that always does extra work. If I do a batch operation of multiple insertions (using transactions), it will occur after each insert there, no?

Comment: Some people hate triggers, I love them :-) Yes, it's extra work on every insert (and with another DBMS I'd make this an after statement trigger, not an after row trigger), but the trigger guarantees consistency. Your rule (maximum of 400 rows, the newest dates kept) is always obeyed. There can never be a situation when there are more than 400 rows in the table, because your trigger ensures that.

Comment: I see. Thank you. The disadvantage of not using it, is to remember to add protection in code that does the same. Might be more efficient, but could lead to bugs in case you forget it.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the created trigger? Or to delete manually (till reaching X items or less) ? I think this trigger removes only one item at a time, so maybe it's better to have a special deletion instead. I used this: `"DELETE FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM $TABLE_NAME ORDER BY $COLUMN_NAME_DATE DESC LIMIT -1 OFFSET $MAX_ITEMS)"` . Got from here: https://kruxor.com/view/code/0d83I/function-to-delete-older-sqlite-records-when-the-limit-is-reached/ . I wonder though: what if I just order by ID. Maybe I can just use "<=" instead of "in (...)".